# Заполнение массива значениями

Tags: javascript, angularjs

У меня есть пара массивов. Нужно занести определенные значения в нужные места. Здесь даже не столько AngularJS нужен, сколько чистый JS: проход по массивам и т.д.

Мои массивы:

- `$scope.usersNew` - массив пользователей с ответами на вопрос анкеты. Структура такая:

  - `id` - идентификатор, понятно.
  - `user` - имя пользователя,
  - `questions` - массив ответов на вопросы. Его структура следующая:

    - `id` вопроса,
    - `name` вопроса,
    - `answer` - собственно, ответ. По умолчанию записана строка `"No answer"`.
- `$scope.anss` - массив всех ответов из базы данных. Структура (та ее часть, которую я использую):

  - `sessionID` - идентификатор сессии, аналог имени пользователя,

    - `questionAnswer` - структура, в которой хранится информация о вопросе и
      ответе. Из нее беру:

      - `question` - структура с информацией о вопросе. Я использую только поле `id`,
      - `answer` - структура с информацией об ответе. Я использую поле `text`

Мой код:

```
// формирование массива пользователей с ответами
    // проход по пользователя
    for (var k = 0; k < $scope.usersNew.length; k++) {
        // проход по ответам
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.anss.length; i++) {
            // принадлежность ответа пользователю
            if ($scope.anss[i].sessionID == $scope.usersNew[k].user) {
                // проход по ответам пользователя
                for (var j = 0; j < $scope.usersNew[k].questions.length; j++) {
                    // соответствие ответов по id вопроса
                    if ($scope.usersNew[k].questions[j].id ==
                        $scope.anss[i].questionAnswer.question.id) {
                        // присвоение ответа пользователю
                        $scope.usersNew[k].questions[j].answer =
                            $scope.anss[i].questionAnswer.answer.text;
                        break; break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Дебаггер показал, что в строке присвоения ответа пользователю программа записывает этот ответ сразу всем пользователям, хотя пользователи вроде как перебираются в самом верхнем `for`.

У меня появилась мысль: может, дело в том, как я заполняла первый массив `usersNew`? Когда записывала в поля `answer` значение `"No answer"`, это выглядело примерно так:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.anss.length; i++) {
    var item = { id: "", user: "", questions: {} }
    item.id = $scope.anss[i].id;
    item.user = $scope.anss[i].sessionID;
    item.questions = $scope.arrForAns;
    users.push(item);
}
```

Где `$scope.arrForAns` - массив, созданный таким образом:

```
$scope.arrForAns = answers.questions;
// answers.questions - это массив объектов, который я достала из JSON, там уже есть id и name
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.arrForAns.length; i++) {
    $scope.arrForAns[i].answer = "No answer";
}
```

Я вроде читала, уже не уверена где, что с присвоением массивов есть загвоздка: что копируются не данные, а ссылки, и, возможно, в памяти лежит один несчастный массив `questions` на всех пользователей, и он-то и терзается со всех сторон.
Или я ошибаюсь, и это я читала о чем-то другом.

Comment: Не по теме вопроса: а второй `break`, так сказать, "на счастье"?

Comment: вроде того) там и первый не особо и нужен, забыла удалить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да. Для всего, кроме примитивных типов копируется ссылка.

К примитивным типам относятся созданные без использования new числа, строки и bool'ы, а также null и undefined.

PS: Не лень было такой вопрос задавать вместо того, чтобы погуглить про передачу по ссылке?

---

> гугл объяснил в чем дело, но его решение почему-то не помогает

Не очень разобрался со всей структурой, но подозреваю, что это из-за того, что внутри массива тоже ссылки. Ангуляр позволяет сделать глубокую копию при помощи `angular.copy`:

```
item.questions = angular.copy($scope.arrForAns);
```

Comment: не лень) я надеялась на помощь, гугл объяснил в чем дело, но его решение почему-то не помогает

Comment: @petrusevka, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Regent, вернул.

Comment: здорово, пока не разобралась что за "глубокая копия", но она помогла. Значит, пойду разбираться. Спасибо большое)

Comment: @petrusevka, пожалуйста. PS: А ответ принять?)

Comment: пардон, я тут новичок, еще разбираюсь куда нажимать надо) вроде приняла

Comment: @petrusevka, ага :)

Answer (score 0):

Хронический пример "Closures". Самый простой способ решения - поместить содержание внутренних `for(){}` на тот же уровень, где находится сам цикл, например:

```
function closure1() {
    function binder1(x){
        return function(){
            return x;
        };
    }
    var arr = [], i;
    for (i = 0; i <10; i++){
        arr[i] = binder1(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(closure1());
```

Или заменить присвоение ответа пользователю на:

```
// соответствие ответов по id вопроса
if ($scope.usersNew[k].questions[j].id == $scope.anss[i].questionAnswer.question.id) {
    // присвоение ответа пользователю
    (function(k, j, i) {
        return function() {
            $scope.usersNew[k].questions[j].answer = $scope.anss[i].questionAnswer.answer.text;
        };
    })(k, j, i)
}
```

Проверять, если честно, лень, но смысл в том, что вам надо создать ещё один контекст для хранения `j`, `i` и `k`.